# Change formatting UNIX TImestamp to database

Tags: php, date-format, unix-timestamp

I am completing a tutorial which can be found here...http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/

I am having problems getting the correct date format into the database. I have successfully add JQuery UI calendar with a format of dateformat: "yy-mm-dd" but I want to add the date in the format "dd-mm-yy"

The UNIX Timestamp always seems to put the year first eg. 2010-04-03

This is a line of code from my PHP extracting the date...

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles ORDER BY " . mysql_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";
```

This is one adding the date which is the important bit as most of the users will understand the dd-mm-yy format better...

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO articles ( publicationDate, title, summary, content ) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(:publicationDate), :title, :summary, :content )";
```

Any help greatly appreciated as I'm at a lose, even after reading part of the PHP Manual.

Many thanks,
CD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is that YY-MM-DD is stored instead of DD-MM-YY, why not reverse it?

```
list($yy, $mm, $dd) = explode("-", $datestring);
$ddmmyy = "$dd-$mm-$yy";
```

Comment: Thanks. I am now using list ( $d, $m, $y ) = $publicationDate;

Answer (score 2):

That's not a unix timestamp. That's a normal MySQL-formatted date/datetime field. A Unix timestamp is just the number of seconds since Jan 1/1970, and looks nothing like a formatted date. e.g.

```
'2011-10-31 15:01:00' in mysql is 1320094860 in timestamp format
```

If you want to change the format the date comes out of MySQL in, you can use the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function

Comment: So I should remove the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function and replace with DATE_FORMAT(date,format)?

Comment: depends on what you'll be using the value for. Passing the database date to a JS date picker, you'd want unix_timestamp, but for displaying a "pretty" string to a user, you'll want DATE_FORMAT.